# Regular Expression to Match All Characters after another Regex Match

Tags: c#, regex

I know this may sound a little confusing, so I am open to suggestions on renaming the title.

Basically I have string such as C:...\Downloads\Folder\SubFolder\SubSubFolder. and I want to return the SubFolder and SubSubFolder only.

So far, my Regex looks like `(?=\\Downloads\\.*?\\).*` which matches `Downloads\Folder\SubFolder\SubSubFolder`.

Does anybody have any Ideas what I am missing????

All the solutions below seem to work (except if you didn't know "Folder"). Potentially a bug with the tool I was using to test the regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a single `<`. You want a look-behind (`(?<=...)`), but you have a look-ahead (`(?=...)`).

In other words, you need `(?<=\\Downloads\\.*?\\).*`.

Comment: You are right, I was using the wrong regex operator! GSkinner told me the (?<..) was positive lookahead. I haven't tested this in my web Application, but tried in GSkinner and it didn't work. Our solution was close to this, but we used some logic to work out what "Folder" would be and then replaced .*? with that. Tested on http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx and this worked

Comment: Marked this as the accepted answer because it was closest to my original post :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the end of the string and non-backslash sequence:

```
/([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)$/
```

Comment: Did you test this? I am using gskinner.com/RegExr and it won't match

Comment: ested on derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/… and this worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's not regex but here's how I'd do it.

```
string marker = @"\Downloads\Folder\";
int i = path.IndexOf(marker);
if (i >= 0)
    return path.Substring(i + marker.Length);
```

Comment: That returns Folder and I really just want SubFolder and SubSubFolder

Comment: @AnthonyWood: Well, I was offering an approach. I've updated the code to do what you want, but it's not really clear if the name Folder will change. (BTW, my brother's name is Anthony Wood.)

Comment: Lol, thats a bit of a coincidence. But it still doesn't work because folder is a variable length string. Thanks for your help, but we got this working because we knew what would be passed in there

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will return two named groups (sub, subsub) in a regex match.

```
(?<=\\Downloads\\[^\\]+\\)(?<sub>[^\\]+)\\(?<subsub>[^\\]+)
```

Retrieving the groups:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\\Downloads\\[^\\]+\\)(?<sub>[^\\]+)\\(?<subsub>[^\\]+)");
var match = regex.Match(@"C:\...");
var sub = match.Groups["sub"].Value;
var subsub = match.Groups["subsub"].Value;
```

Comment: This didn't work, I did my testing on GSkinner/RegExr. Is this different from the .NET Regex Engine.

Comment: ested on derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/… and this worked